# Secure USB stick recommendation

Tags: usb-drive

I've read a lot on this site about how USB sticks are inherently (I assume) insecure. There are analyses about how just by plugging it in to your laptop might initialize some program to be run without you knowing, and so can install malware on your computer.

With this in mind, I am wondering if it is even a good idea to buy a USB stick, and if so, what are some examples of relatively secure options.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

USB sticks you own and control bought from a trusted source are fine. Trusted source being a known retailer or brand.
Its picking up a random one off the street or a receiving one from an untrusted source that introduces risk.

Think of it as software if you buy an application from a trusted source you run it on your machine - if you grab something from a torrent well roll the dice.

If you are **really** worried buy one and configure your system to only allow USB storage from that particular device. Windows you can do this via group policy.

Comment: Agree.  Would like to add...What defines trusted source depends on your risk appetite.  Are you guarding national defense secrets?  A known brand is not "trusted" enough.  Are you just trying not to get pwned on your gaming laptop?  A known brand would be considered "trusted"